# Java: Determine JFrame/Window-Size in Null-Layout

Tags: java, swing, window, size, null-layout-manager

I have the following java problem:

I definitively have to use a null layout set by

```
mainWindow.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

with mainWindow being a JFrame. Now, I want to place objects (JLabel for example) absolutely but depending on the window size.
For that, I have to determine the size of the JFrame or that of the contentPane. Is there any way to get that information in a null-layout?

I have tried:

```
mainWindow.getContentPane().getBounds();
mainWindow.getContentPane().getPreferredSize();
mainWindow.getContentPane().getSize();
mainWindow.getContentPane().getInsets();
```

And the same for mainWindow itself. But for all of them, I just get zeros.

Either google holds no answer or I've looked for the wrong keywords.

I would be glad to get any advice or link to a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).  What you are seeing, is one of the **many** reasons that experienced programmers advise *against* using `null` layouts.

Comment: *"I definitively have to use a null layout.."*  That is never true,  ***ever!***  See [this thread](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1353374) for more.

Comment: Insets ............................

Comment: You might try [*Creating a Custom Layout Manager*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html).

Comment: `But for all of them, I just get zeros.` - that is because components don't have a size until the frame has been packed or made visible. `Now, I want to place objects (JLabel for example) absolutely but depending on the window size.` - that is the definition of a layout manager, you position the component based on the size of the window.

Comment: Ok. I see your points. Maybe I just don't have enough experience with the layout manager system. I'll try to build my layout with a custom layout manager.
Thanks very much for your replies!

Comment: Tip:  Add @camickr (or whoever - the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.